# Circularity when using base and derived class as arrays in both

Tags: c++, class, c++11, derived

I am trying so make a class which holds a arbitrary value as specified in NBT format. It is a kind of json, but more advanced.

So, I make a class which holds a ListValue(a value without a name) and another one which holds a Value(with name). In the derived class, I lift = operator from base

```
using ListValue::operator=;
```

In a third file I have two usings:

```
using CompoundData = std::vector<Value>;
using ListData = std::vector<ListValue>;
```

ListValue has a private member as:

```
union ValueHolder
{
    Byte vByte;
    Short vShort;
    Int vInt;
    Long vLong;
    Float vFloat;
    Double vDouble;
    String* pString;
    CompoundData* pCompound;
} mData;
```

(I'll add ListData* later)

The problem is I have absolutely no idea how how to include all these headers  so it will work with the circularity. I tried several forward declarations and containers as vector or vector with smart pointers for breaking it, but nothing worked for me.

I would be very very grateful if you could help me to give me a(n) idea / solution for my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: you should try to create a minimal example that reproduce your problem. The compiler message is usually a good starting point.

Comment: Circularity comes almost all the time from a mistake in design... Change design to not have circularity, you will save you a lot of trouble in future. You have many options to achieve that, and first one which comes to my mind is polymorphism

Comment: What is NBT format?  Also,why are your types capilitized?  A typo?

Comment: Do you realize that a `union` will occupy as much space as the largest member?  I'm asking because I see a `Byte` type listed with a `Long` type, which seems a waste of space.

Comment: Since the code posted here does not mention any headers it's impossible to explain how to "include all these headers". Show real code, not handwaving descriptions.

Comment: NBT is the format used by Minecraft to store it's data files. The types are capitalized because they are using aliases to int8_t, 16, etc. which match the size and the type specified in the format. I will add more code and infos when I'll get home.

Comment: And yes, it may be a waste of space, but I don't have any other idea(I already failed to implement a polymorphic abordation). jsoncpp uses the same idea and is pretty fast and popular, so it looked like a good way to me.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is:

```
struct CompoundData;
struct ListData;
```

then elsewhere:

```
struct CompoundData : std::vector<Value> {
  using std::vector<Value>::vector;
  CompoundData& operator=(std::vector<Value> const& o) {
    static_cast<std::vector<Value>&>(*this)=o;
    return *this;
  }
  CompoundData& operator=(std::vector<Value> && o) {
    static_cast<std::vector<Value>&>(*this)=std::move(o);
    return *this;
  }
  CompoundData(std::vector<Value> const& o):
    std::vector<Value>(o)
  {}
  CompoundData(std::vector<Value> && o):
    std::vector<Value>(std::move(o))
  {}
  CompoundData()=default;
  CompoundData(CompoundData const&)=default;
  CompoundData(CompoundData &&)=default;
  CompoundData& operator=(CompoundData const&)=default;
  CompoundData& operator=(CompoundData &&)=default;
};
```

which is a bunch of boilerplate saying "no, I'm not really different than the `std::vector` I inherit from", and the same for `ListData`.